# Accounting for spatial clumping when determining the variability of a sample

Tags: spatial, distance-functions, variability, clumping

I am looking for a way to account for the spatial clumping/clustering/ in my data.

My data comes from 50m line transects.  For each transect I recorded the grass height at 2m intervals, giving me 25 measurements per transect.  Below are the profiles of 3 hypothetical transects showing the height of the grass at each point:

[image]

Using this data I can compare the structure of the grass along each transect. 
 I can look at the quantity of grass but I am also interested in how this quantity of grass is distributed.  Transect a is clearly less variable than transects b and c and I can confirm this by calculating e.g. the standard error.  My problem is that, because b and c both have 12 points with a height of 3cm and 13 points with a heights of 10cm, they have the same standard error although there are clear, and potentially ecologically important, differences in their structure.

So I am looking for a way to differentiate between the variability in transects b and c.  Rather than comparing each point to the mean to determine the variability (which is what standard error does) I thought there might be a way weight this by the similarity of a point to its nearest neighbours so that transect b shows less variability than transect c.  I thought there might be a distance based method but I haven't been able to find one.  Ultimately I would like to have a single value for each transect which represents this adjusted variability.

I will be using R for the analysis so if anyone knows a function which will do this it would be much appreciated!

Finally, the grass height values used to generate the above graphs are:

a: 10, 10, 10, 10, 3, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 14, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 4, 10, 10,
 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10

b: 10, 10, 10, 3, 3, 3, 10, 10, 10, 3, 3, 3, 10, 10, 10, 3, 3, 3, 10, 10,
 10, 3, 3, 3, 10

c: 10, 3, 10, 3, 10, 3, 10, 3, 10, 3, 10, 3, 10, 3, 10, 3, 10, 3, 10, 3,
 10, 3, 10, 3, 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about computing standard deviations on spatially-lagged values ?

---

Assuming that your space is $1$-dimensional, and that coordinates, $c_i$, are those charted, i.e. $i$ ranging from $1$ to $25$. A first thing one can do is computing the $25\times 25$ distance matrix, $\boldsymbol{D}$, whose closed form expression is

$\boldsymbol{D} = [d_{ij}] = [|c_i - c_j|]$ where $\{(i,j)|i \in [1,25]$ and $j \in [1,25]\}$

With $\boldsymbol{D}$ in hand, one creates a (so-called) spatial weight matrix, commonly denoted by $\boldsymbol{W}$, defined as

$\boldsymbol{W} = [w_{ij}] =\begin{cases} 
      [d_{ij}^{-1}] & \text{if $i\neq j$}, \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

And one then makes it be [right stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix) (real square matrix with each row summing to $1$), i.e.

$\boldsymbol{W}^{*} = [w_{ij}/\sum_{k=1}^{25}w_{ik}]$

Actually, what one is going to do is working with spatially lagged vectors instead of the original ones, i.e. working with transformed versions of `a`, `b` and `c` instead of working with those directly. Those transformed vectors will be formed over components that consist of neighbors (distance weighted) average. The variance of these averages will be low for spatially-clustered heights.

---

In R you would do

```
> x = seq(1,25)
> x
> x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

Then, since the space is a line, one would compute the second dimension, `y`, (required by the package I have in mind), as $0$s, as follows

```
> y = rep(0, each=25)
> y
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

One loads the library [distances](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/distances/distances.pdf)

```
> library(distances)
```

creates the distance matrix as

```
> D <- as.matrix(distances(data=data.frame(x = x, y=y)))
```

one takes its ***elementwise*** inverse

```
> Di <- 1/D
```

one replaces (in place) `Di`'s diagonal `Inf` elements with $0$

```
> diag(Di)<-0
```

defines `W` as the right stochastic version of `Di`

```
> W <- Di/rowSums(Di)
> sum(W)
[1] 25
```

---

One can now get your 3 hypothetical transects

```
> a <- c(10,10,10,10,3,10,10,10,10,10,14,10,10,10,10,10,4,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10)
> b <- c(10,10,10,3,3,3,10,10,10,3,3,3,10,10,10,3,3,3,10,10,10,3,3,3,10)
> c <- c(10,3,10,3,10,3,10,3,10,3,10,3,10,3,10,3,10,3,10,3,10,3,10,3,10)
```

one spatially lags these three vectors

```
> Wa <- W%*%a
> Wb <- W%*%b
> Wc <- W%*%c
```

recalling that your sample standard deviations of `a`, `b` and `c` respectively are

```
> sd(a)
[1] 2.01825
> sd(b)
[1] 3.569314
> sd(c)
[1] 3.569314
```

notice that those of `Wa`, `Wb` and `Wc` are

```
> sd(Wa)
[1] 0.3961341
> sd(Wb)
[1] 0.4542065
> sd(Wc)
[1] 0.866519
```

which provides you with a *way to differentiate between the variability in transects `b` and `c`*. In this case, the std of `Wc` is higher than the one of `Wb`.

---

As mentioned previously, when one does, say, `Wc <- W%*%c`, with `W` being row-stochastic, one creates a vector whose components consist of neighbors (distance weighted) average. Since heights are less spatially clustered in `c`, these distance weighted averages exhibit a higher variance that those in `b`.

Finally, so as to create a synthetic indicator of the two types of variance, i.e. the spatial and the non-spatial ones, you could summarize them in one object by computing an [euclidean norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm).

```
> ( sd(Wa)^2 + sd(a)^2 )^.5
[1] 2.056758
> ( sd(Wb)^2 + sd(b)^2 )^.5
[1] 3.598097
> ( sd(Wc)^2 + sd(c)^2 )^.5
[1] 3.67299
```

*You probably already know that, but recall that norms, be them euclidean or not, are often used to measure how "1-dimension big" are multidimensional objects.* In our case, the first dimension is the one of *non-spatial* variance, and the second dimension is the one of *spatial-variance*.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks for such a comprehensive and detailed answer, it worked perfectly!  Didn't make a huge amount of difference when compared to just the SD, I guess my data isn't as clumped as the hypothetical examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bound to reducing the variability to one number...you could try some form of quadrat variance analysis, which would allow you to compare the patch/gap scales among transects. If your goal is to describe/compare the patterns, this might be a better option.

Unfortunately, I am not aware of a package in R that does quadrat variance analysis; your best bet (at the present time) would be PASSaGE 2. If you are clever, you could write a function in R that calls the batch command in PASSaGE 2...or just write your own function in R.

Quadrat variance methods were developed by plant ecologists and are well described in books by M. Dale (1999)..and Fortin and Dale (2005)...and various papers going back to the 1950s. The user manual in PASSaGE 2 also provides the basic theory.